# Streaming video (C# using FFmpeg AutoGen) sends multiple data requests

Tags: c#, google-chrome, video, ffmpeg, streaming

I've written a video generator that rights a video in h264 format (mp4).  When I stream the video from my azure service, i'm seeing the following network traffic:

[image]

The AVCodecContext layout I'm using is as follows:

```
AVCodec* videoCodec = ffmpeg.avcodec_find_encoder(AVCodecID.AV_CODEC_ID_H264)
AVCodecContext* videoCodecContext = ffmpeg.avcodec_alloc_context3(videoCodec);
videoCodecContext->bit_rate = 400000;
videoCodecContext->width = 1280;
videoCodecContext->height = 720;
videoCodecContext->gop_size = 12;
videoCodecContext->max_b_frames = 1;
videoCodecContext->pix_fmt = videoCodec->pix_fmts[0];
videoCodecContext->codec_id = videoCodec->id;
videoCodecContext->codec_type = videoCodec->type;
videoCodecContext->time_base = new AVRational
{
    num = 1,
    den = 30
};

ffmpeg.av_opt_set(videoCodecContext->priv_data, "preset", "ultrafast");
```

I'm also tried setting the "movflags" option for avformat_write_header() via an AVDictionary, but then av_write_trailer() returns -2, cause the file to not finish writing.

I cannot figure out how to solve this problem.  Videos generating using Windows Movie Maker stream perfectly.

I know this has something to do with mdat and mov positions.

Also, this appears to only happening in Google Chrome.

Comment: You probably need to add `av_opt_set(formatContext, "movflags", "+faststart", 0);`

Comment: Done that already, it returns a -1414549496 error.

Comment: That's `AVERROR_OPTION_NOT_FOUND`. What's the code where you mux and write to file?

Comment: I'm assuming that the "formatContext" in that code is for the AVFormatContext* object?

Comment: That's right. ....

Comment: If its an option not found error, then surely setting it that way is not right?  I've also tried setting a AVDictionary object and passing it to avformat_write_header(), which is fine.  However, then av_write_trailer() returns -2.

Comment: Ok, one last try. movflags is a private option, so try `av_opt_set(formatContext->priv_data, "movflags", "+faststart", 0);`

Comment: It returns a -1414549496 error again :(

Comment: I've moved the code you suggested to (formatContext->priv_data) to after the header has been written, and then av_write_trailer() returns -2.

Comment: In FFmpeg's source code, the faststart routine is executed by `static int mov_write_trailer(AVFormatContext *s)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, figured this out.  I've been writing the video frames first and the audio frames afterwards.  Instead, you have to write them side by side in order for faststart to actually work and allow the video to stream.

So, write a specific amount of audio and then determine if a video frame should be written by checking the timebases against the current writing indexes.

This [example](http://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/doc_2examples_2muxing_8c-example.html) will show you how its done.

Also, to get the video and audio streams to have accurate PTS/DTS values, look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38198052/sync-audio-video-in-mp4-using-autogen-ffmpeg-library) question.